# Why does the QGIS Conversion (Translate Format) fail in batch mode? QGIS 3.4.4

Tags: qgis

QGIS Conversion (Translate Format) will convert individual file from tif and tfw to tiff that does not need the tfw. But the batch process gives the error "Wrong or missing output value: Converted (row 1)".

I don't see any place on the batch screen that asks for output setting. I set the output to float 32 as one post suggested but got the same error

I have about 100 tif/tfw files I want to convert.

There was a similar question but it had no answer